# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to create repository method in Spring Data JPA like:

```
List<MemberSubscription> findAllByOrderByCreatedAsc(Example<MemberSubscription> memberSubscription);
```

but it give me error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.abcfinancial.api.subscription.repository.SubscriptionMembersRepository.findAllByOrderByCreatedAsc(org.springframework.data.domain.Example)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$CriteriaQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createQueryParameterSetter$1(ParameterBinderFactory.java:139)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createSetters$0(ParameterBinderFactory.java:131)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createCriteriaBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.getBinder(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:248)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:77)
        ... 86 common frames omitted
```

table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.member_subscription
(
  loc_id uuid NOT NULL,
  mesu_created timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  mesu_deactivated timestamp(6) without time zone,
  m_id uuid NOT NULL,
  sub_id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_member_subscription_subscription FOREIGN KEY (sub_id)
      REFERENCES public.subscription (sub_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT composite_unique_member_subscription UNIQUE (m_id, sub_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.member_subscription
  OWNER TO platformuser;
```

I want to find all data from table in sorting order with create(i.e. created date).

Spring Data query parameters are replaced based on their positions. But this might go wrong and binding could be error prone. Hence it is suggested to use @Param annotation in the method parameter to bind the query parameter names. And in the query, you need to use :paramName to indicate that the same paramName is to bind with the method parameter

Answer (score -2):

```
@Entity
public class ABCConfig {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ABCConfigPK id;

    @Embeddable
public class ABCConfigPK {

    private Long ABCTypeId;
    private String cId;


    @Repository
public interface SpringDataABCConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<ABCConfig, ABCConfigPK> {

    List<ABCConfig> findByIdABCTypeIdAndcardId(Long ABCTypeId,Long cId);
```

Comment: ABCTypeId and cId are composite keys